# get all the json object with a specified conditions

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonarray as given below

```
[{"key1":10},{"key1":20},{"key1":30}]
```

I want to get all the json objects with a specified condition. say get all the json objects with key1 less than 25. so my sql query should return this list

```
[{"key1":10},{"key1":20}]
```

what is the resultant SQL query for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d3eaf6355a37f597144123705cb7d313)

```
SELECT
    json_agg(elements)                       -- 3
FROM mytable,
    json_array_elements(mydata) as elements  -- 1
WHERE (elements ->> 'key1')::int < 25        -- 2
```

1. Extract the JSON array: Each element is now in an own record
2. Filter by the value. Notice, that `->>` returns a type `text`, so you need to cast it into type `int` in your case
3. Reaggregate the remaining elements into the new array

Comment: tried this query didnt work

SELECT
    json_agg(elements)                       -- 3
FROM object_repository,
    json_array_elements(core_attributes) as elements  -- 1
WHERE (elements ->> 'key1')::int < 25        -- 2


core_attributes is json b column name


error got

EQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function json_array_elements(jsonb) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 86

Comment: You have type `jsonb`, not type `json` as you wrote in your question. Well, in that case, you need `jsonb_agg()` instead of `json_agg()` as well as `jsonb_array_elements` instead of `json_array_elements`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8bd5ebad8635e0c43916b052fe7738fe

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later you can use a JSON path function:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(the_column, '$[*] ? (@.key1 <= 25)')
from the_table
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f5abd4472028141e030b33cf82010f87)